# How to disable copying Java Resources in Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, build, gradle

When I run the building task in gradle, it copies all the java resources (from src/main/resources) into build/resources. Because I have too heavy files there my build process significantly slower that it could be.

Is there any way to disable copying them and force java to use them just from src/main/resources ?

Comment: You could argue that if you just want to use the files from the file system, these are not "resources" in the sense that they should get packaged into the JAR in the first place. Consequently, you could just move them to a directory like "assets" (that is not processed by Gradle) and use them straight from there.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you don't need any resource filtering and don't need access to resources from tests in the same project, you can do:

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = []
jar {
    from "src/main/resources"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more explicit way to suppress copying resources is this:

```
processResources {
    exclude '**/*'
}
```